# iPad mail application floats attachments over the body of an SSRS report

Tags: ipad, email, reporting-services, attachment

We have a .NET application that sends SSRS reports and file attachments in an email.
When viewing these emails on an iPad or iPhone, the attachments seem to float over the body of the email thereby masking the contents in our report.

It almost looks like the mail application cannot detect the end of the body of our email and is placing its attachment controls on top of it.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Is there something we could fix in the report so the mail application may handle it better?

Comment: Have you checked out the source of those e-mails yet, to confirm your suspicions?

Comment: Apparently, Apple doesnt support MHT. They only support HTML. Our application was downloading reports as an MHT document and sending it as the body of the email. It screws up the placement of their attachment controls.

Comment: Just did... Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was Apple's mail app renders MHT which we were sending out as the body of the email. But it cannot detect the end of the MHT document and misplaces its attachment controls. The remedy is to use html instead.

When we moved to using HTML, we had to force the HTML out of Quirks mode into Strict mode to get it working correctly.

Comment: How do you fix this for SSRS when using the subscription

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the attachment buttons were overlaying at the top of the HTML page. Amol's answer was right the HTML needed to be forced into [Strict Mode](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) in order for Apple's inbox to correctly position its attachment buttons.

I wanted to share my solution:

```
html = html.Replace("PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\"", "");
```

Before sending the report I did a string replace to remove The code from the doctype. This prevents Apple's mail app from going into [Quirks mode](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).